# Using ASP.Net MVC 4 with a Content Management System

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a CMS running on ColdFusion, for which I normally have a front-end also running on ColdFusion. For learning reasons, I now want to realize the front-end with the ASP.Net MVC 4 Framework. For a MVC application you normally have a simple controller/action routing, which wouldn't make any sense with my CMS, since it is structured completely different.

My CMS has a navigation module as basis, which handles the whole structure and routing of the website. On every navigation entry I can assign one page, which can have multiple elements (for example simple HTML code, a news module or a gallery module).

**Site structure example:**

- home **->** page **->** elements (html)
- about **->** page **->** elements (html, ...)

  - our-company **->** page **->** elements (html, news, gallery)
  - our-products **->** page **->** elements (html, ...)
- contact **->** page **->** elements (html, contact form)

So, if a user opens "www.example.com/about/our-company.html" in the browser, the application than finds the responsible navigation entry "our-company" which is a child of the entry "about". Now it should render the elements "html", "news" and "gallery" which are assigned to the page for this navigation entry.

Now my question is, how would you realize this with the ASP.Net MVC Framework? Is it even possible? Does MVC make sense here?

I would like to have a model, controller and views for each page element. Do I need something like a base controller which would render multiple actions in different (element-)controllers?

**Update**

The site structure is not static, it's dynamic and it's managed by the CMS.

Another example: www.example.com/de/about/more/andmore/something.html

In this example I would search for the key "something" in the navigation table and get the responsible page. Now I would like to render all elements (I just call them elements) for this page. Each element should have it's own controller and multiple actions.

Comment: most CMS do not have physical pages. Take DotNetNuke for instance, all the user pages, that those pages contain, titles, text, etc. are all stored in MS SQL.

Comment: My CMS also stores all pages in MS SQL. The URL's in my examples are just optimized for search engines.

Comment: I guess what I meant by that was, you need a handler or controller or route to do the hard core routing. You'll have to look up the navigation in the database from one of those. You can use wildcard `/foo/{*}/bar` routes to respond to everything

Comment: Basically I could create one routing rule which forwards every request to a single `NavigationController` which finds the responsible page in the database. But my problem is, that every page can have one or more "page elements" (that's just what I call them). A "page element" could be a simple html text, a picture, a gallery, a news list, a dynamic form or even a whole shop. Since we have around 20 of these "page elements" I'm wondering where to put the code for these. I think the best solution would be, to create a Controller for each "page element"......

Comment: ... But how can my `NavigationController` render multiple "page element"-Controller?

Answer (score 0):

### Asp.net MVC default routing seems ok

Default route definition would work in your case just as well. At least I don't see any particular issues with it:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Where you'd have controllers:

- HomeController
- AboutController - with your examply this controller would have `OurCompany` action (/about/ourcompany)
- ContactController
- etc.

### Still not completely clear

But I suppose you should provide your URLs you'd like to have in your application and we'd likely be able to help. I'm not sure what *elements* means in your navigation? How does that translate to URLs?

Comment: @android: So if I understand your routing you want something like: `{lang}/{sections*}/{page}` where sections can consist of several URL segments? Is that what you'd like to have? And if that is affirmative, I'm still not sure about your idea of controllers and *elements*. Are these elements like some sort of page components/parts? So they consist of several HTML elements that are then put on the page along with other components/parts? Like Navigation, user context, post, post comments etc.?